# Override method remove in NSArrayController

Tags: objective-c, overriding, macos

I have override method remove in a NSArrayController (that is linked to Core Data) to remove a row of a NSViewTable:

```
-(void)remove:(id)sender
{
    NSManagedObject *esameToDelete = [[self selectedObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    [self removeObject:esameToDelete];
}
```

**This works but remove a random row of the table**. I have also tried to use
    [super remove:sender]
or a handler that calls `remove` method but the result is the same. What's wrong?

Comment: Your code is working perfectly for me!